# How to refresh detail view and master view at the same time in ios14.2 (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, ios14

Hi I want to refresh the detail view which is triggered by data change under the master view

 My approach is setup a Combine listener and trigger the refresh from the detail view

 It was working on ios13 but I can't make it working on ios14.2, any workaround?

Here is my master view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : MainViewModel
    
    init(){
        viewModel = MainViewModel.shared
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.games ,id:\.self) { game in
                    NavigationLink(destination: self.navDest(game: game)){
                        Text("\(game)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func navDest(game: Int) -> some View{
        print("games value:",game)
        return LazyView(DetailView(game: game ))
    }
}
```

[image: 111]

The master view model listen to the event come from detail view and update the value

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine


class MainViewModel : ObservableObject {

    @Published var games : [Int] = []
    static let shared = MainViewModel()
    private var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []
    
    init(){
        for i in 0...5{
            games.append(i)
        }
        addObservor()
    }
    
    func addObservor(){
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .updateGame)
            .map{$0.object as! Int}
            .sink { [unowned self] (game) in
                self.updateGame(game: game)
            }.store(in: &tickets)
    }
    
    func updateGame(game:Int){
        print("updateView index:",game)
        self.games[game] = 9999
        print("after update",games)
    }
}



import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : DetailViewModel
    
    init(game: Int) {
        print("init detail",game)
        viewModel = DetailViewModel(game:game)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(viewModel.game)")
            Button("update"){
                viewModel.sendUpdate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the update from detail view, it should refresh the master and detail view at the same time.
(The flow is DetailViewModlel->MainViewModlel->Refresh MainView ->Refresh DetailView (which is currently display)) But it not work on iOS 14.2

[image: 3]

```
    import Foundation
import SwiftUI


class DetailViewModel : ObservableObject {

    var period : String = ""
    var game : Int = 0
    
//    init(period:String,game: Int){
//        self.period = period
        init(game: Int){
        self.game = game
    }

    func sendUpdate(){
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .updateGame, object:  game)
    }
}

extension Notification.Name {
    static let updateGame = Notification.Name("updateGame")
   
}
struct LazyView<Content: View>: View {
    let build: () -> Content
    init(_ build: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.build = build
    }
    var body: Content {
        build()
    }
}
```

DetailView

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : DetailViewModel
    
    init(game: Int) {
        print("init detail",game)
        viewModel = DetailViewModel(game:game)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(viewModel.game)")
            Button("update"){
                viewModel.sendUpdate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have logged down the debug message, it seem like the data did changed but the view didn't.

Comment: The trigger area is by NotificationCenter under DetailViewModel. MainView has an observe to receive it and triggered the reload on both MainView and DetailView. If I press the back button from DetailView, I can see the data is refreshed but the detailView before press the back didn't.

Comment: I'm getting something very similar, working fine in Xcode 12.1 but not updating the view presented by the NavigationView in Xcode 12.2.
It's fine with a 14.1 Simulator inside of Xcode 12.2, but not with 14.2 sims or devices